# Item has already been added.Error during Windows Service Installation

Tags: c#, windows-services, installation

I am installing a windows Service.When the installer   finishes the code written in install event. It gives a following error.

> Error 1001. Item has already been added. Key in dictionary:
>   '_reserved_lastInstallerAttempted' Key being added:
>   '_reserved_lastInstallerAttempted',

I have searched various possibilities of the above key in registry but in vain.I have used try catch .The error neither shows any stacktrace or source.

Comment: You may want to take a look at the event viewer.

Answer (score 4):

Check your `Installer` implementation the `void Install(IDictionary stateServer)` override to see if you call `base.Install(stateServer)` **twice**.